# Nginx 'No input file specified.' error on laravel project using php71

Tags: php, nginx

This is what appear in my error.log

> 1498#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in Unknown on line 0
>   Unable to open primary script: /var/www/public/index.php (Operation not permitted)" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "example.com"

My permission for /var/www/public/index.php is

> -rwxrwxrwx   1 user  staff  1782 15 Mar 12:17 index.php

My server conf

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name example.com;

        client_max_body_size 100M;

        root /var/www/public;

        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri /index.php =404;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
               fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }
}
```

Comment: not only does the file needs the permission, the directories requires the read and execute permissions too.

Comment: i have the same permissions from var till www till public till index.php